# How to set two images next to each other without using a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

So say I have two `ImageView`s. Without a `LinearLayout`, what's the easiest way/best way to set them next to each other programatically? *(I'm using a `RelativeLayout`)*

Currently, what I have is two `ImageView`s, one named `A`, and the other named `B`.

`A` is drawn first, then `B`.

What I did was :

```
B.setTranslationX(A.getRight());
```

What this is SUPPOSED to do is set `B`'s X coordinate of the left side to `A`'s X coordinate of its right side, which would put them next to each other.

But when I do this, I get 0 for both `A`'s left, `A`'s right, `B`'s left, and `B`'s right.

So in actuality, `A` and `B` are on top of each other, which is not what I want.

Comment: It is easy to set them in the layout right? Is there any purpose to set them programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ImageView iv1 = new ImageView(context);
ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(context);

your_relative_layout.addView(iv1, layoutParams);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, iv1.getId());
your_relative_layout.addView(iv2, layoutParams);
```

This code adds a rule to the LayoutParams that `iv2` would be to the right of `iv1`